# Problema al cargar documentos en sesiones simultaneas C#

Tags: c#, .net

Soy nuevo en C# y estoy realizando un proyecto con el cual cargo documentos pero estoy presentando un problema a cargar los documentos simultáneamente con diferentes usuarios. Realizo un breakpoint para darme cuenta de la matricula que tiene el primer usuario que ingresa. Al iniciar cada sesión se ingresa la matricula correspondiente.

Aquí esta la matricula cuando cargo el documento desde una sesión del navegador.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y aquí esta la otra sesión en modo incógnito

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El problema que se viene presentando es que al cargar el documento desde la segunda sesión (incógnito) se carga directamente a la primera matricula, quiero decir el documento se carga al primero que se envíe la peticion, como lo muestro en la siguiente imagen, doy click en el primero y se carga el documento sin problema en la sesión correspondiente pero al dar click en la segunda sesión se carga en la primera matricula se que dio click anteriormente.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Alguien que tenga mas experiencia en el manejo de sesiones simultaneas puede explicar porque sucede o que solución me puede aportar.

Adjunto a continuación el código que muestro en la imagen:

```
AxDocumentIndex newDocumentIndex = new AxDocumentIndex("-1",
                        GlobalVariables.Matricula,
                        GlobalVariables.getPdim(GlobalVariables.Matricula),
                        GlobalVariables.Aidy, GlobalVariables.Aidp,
                        GlobalVariables.Fndc, treqCode,
                        GlobalVariables.Aplicacion,
                        DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"));

result = axServicesInterface.CreateNewDocument(sessionTicket, newDocument.ToString(),
                                                                       newDocumentIndex.ToString());
```

**Actualizacion:**

Publico el codigo donde declaro el objeto `GlobalVariables`

```
public static class GlobalVariables
    {
        private static string matricula;
        private static string fndc;
        private static string aidy;
        private static string aidp;
        private static string aplicacion;
        public static readonly string ftpip;
        public static readonly string ftpUser;
        public static readonly string ftpPassword;
        public static readonly string dataSource;
        public static readonly string ftpRuta;
        public static readonly string xtUser;
        public static readonly string xtPass;

        public static string Matricula { get => matricula; set => matricula = value; }
        public static string Fndc { get => fndc; set => fndc = value; }
        public static string Aidy { get => aidy; set => aidy = value; }
        public static string Aidp { get => aidp; set => aidp = value; }
        public static string Aplicacion { get => aplicacion; set => aplicacion = value; }
    }
```

Comment: Puedes publicar el código donde declaras el objeto `GlobalVariables`, es probable que el problema está allí. Si el nombre que le diste, en realidad expresa la intención de su uso, sospecho que puedes haberlo creado como una clase estática o lo usas como Singleton y si es así, definitivamente allí está el problema.

Comment: @PabloGutiérrez Gracias por tu comentario, acabo de publicar el código que me pediste, es posible que ese sea el problema?

Comment: Definitivamente ese es el problema, acabo de publicar una explicación más detallada en mi respuesta y por favor hazme saber si necesitas cualquier aclaratoria adicional.

Comment: @PabloGutiérrez Entiendo el contexto de tu respuesta, podrías por favor aportar un ejemplo en base al código que estoy usando

Comment: Si claro, solo que voy a necesitar un poco más de información para ser lo más preciso posible con el ejemplo. Por favor cuéntame ¿de donde recibes los datos que asignas a `GlobalVariables`?

Comment: @PabloGutiérrez Claro, revisa la actualización 2 es ahí donde recibo los datos si no me equivoco

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/110794/discussion-between-pablo-gutierrez-and-sebastian-salazar).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

El problema ocurre porque el objeto `GlobalVariables` es una clase estática.

Ten en cuenta que cualquier variable estática pública expone un unico contenido a todas las instancias que tienen acceso a ella.

En tu caso, cada valor asignado a cualquiera de las propiedades del objeto `GlobalVariables` será compartido por todas las sesiones que tengan acceso a el, o dicho de otra forma, el último valor asignado, será el que reciban todas las sesiones.

Para resolverlo, necesitas separar cuáles son los miembros de esa clase que deben ser únicos a cada sesión y crear con ellos una nueva clase que no sea estática y que debe ser instanciada para cada nueva sesión.

**Ejemplo:**

Suponiendo que las propiedades únicas para la sesión son las que pasas como argumentos al crear la instancia de `AxDocumentIndex`, puedes crear una nueva clase como la siguiente:

```
public class SesionDeUsuario
{
   public string Matricula { get; set; }
   public string Aidy { get; set; }
   public string Aidp { get; set; }
   public string Fndc { get; set; }
   public string Aplicacion { get; set; }
}
```

Luego en cada peticion que recibes, debes crear una instancia de esta clase y con esto el primer bloque de código quedaría de la siguiente manera:

```
//En este punto se asume que existe una instancia de la clase SesionDeUsuario
//llamada 'sesion' 
//bien sea que fue creada en el mismo método o recibida en un parámetro

AxDocumentIndex newDocumentIndex = new AxDocumentIndex("-1",
                        sesion.Matricula,
                        GlobalVariables.getPdim(sesion.Matricula),
                        sesion.Aidy, sesion.Aidp,
                        sesion.Fndc, treqCode,
                        sesion.Aplicacion,
                        DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"));
```